# Декодирование url в поисковом запросе

Tags: php, url, search

Когда уважаемый посетитель вводит слово, скажем, «алкоголизьм» в текстовое поле поиска и нажимает кнопку «Поиск», то, при get-методе, в адресной строке красуется вот это: [http://site.org/search/?termin=алкоголизьм&submit=Поиск](http://site.org/search/?termin=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC&submit=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA). Это, не хорошо. Нужно как-то декодировать/кодировать параметры termin и submit. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нестандартные символы в URL **всегда** кодируются.
2. Как отображать кодированную строку - как есть, или раскодировать для красоты - это личное дело **браузера**. Сервер на это повлиять никак не может.

Comment: Вот так. То-есть, не стоит заморачиваться?

Comment: Абсолютно не стоит. Я бы только убрал атрибут name у сабмита, чтобы он в адресной строке не болтался